# Raspbian and Netgear 779s LTE modem

Tags: raspbian-stretch, modem, networkmanager

I've been having trouble the last two days figuring out why my NetGear 779s modem isn't working fine with Raspbian.

I installed **NetworManager**, and did `sudo systemctl disable dhcpcd` and `sudo systemctl stop dhcpcd`. I believe that's all I did to make my wifi network interface work for me. I installed it in order to have ModemManager too. 
NetworkManager reports that the connection is up, but it just doesn't seem to work when I ping 8.8.8.8.

I switch the device to modem-mode using:

```
pi@raspi-sort:~ $ sudo usb_modeswitch -p 0fff -v 0846 -S -W
Take all parameters from the command line


 * usb_modeswitch: handle USB devices with multiple modes
 * Version 2.5.0 (C) Josua Dietze 2017
 * Based on libusb1/libusbx

 ! PLEASE REPORT NEW CONFIGURATIONS !

DefaultVendor=  0x0846
DefaultProduct= 0x0fff
SierraMode=1

Look for default devices ...
  found USB ID 0846:0fff
   vendor ID matched
   product ID matched
  found USB ID 0424:7800
  found USB ID 0424:2514
  found USB ID 0424:2514
  found USB ID 1d6b:0002
 Found devices in default mode (1)
Access device 007 on bus 001
Get the current device configuration ...
Current configuration number is 1
Use interface number 9
 with class 8

USB description data (for identification)
>-------------------------
Manufacturer: NETGEAR
     Product: AirCard 779S
  Serial No.: 014260001176522
>-------------------------
Send Sierra control message
-> Run lsusb to note any changes. Bye!
```

After doing that, I check the change with:

```
pi@raspi-sort:~ $ lsusb -t
/:  Bus 01.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=dwc_otg/1p, 480M
    |__ Port 1: Dev 2, If 0, Class=Hub, Driver=hub/4p, 480M
        |__ Port 1: Dev 3, If 0, Class=Hub, Driver=hub/3p, 480M
            |__ Port 1: Dev 4, If 0, Class=Vendor Specific Class, Driver=lan78xx, 480M
            |__ Port 3: Dev 8, If 0, Class=Vendor Specific Class, Driver=, 480M
            |__ Port 3: Dev 8, If 3, Class=Vendor Specific Class, Driver=, 480M
            |__ Port 3: Dev 8, If 8, Class=Vendor Specific Class, Driver=qmi_wwan, 480M
```

At that point nmcli stats showing:

```
cdc-wdm0: disconnected
    1 connection available
    modem (qmi_wwan), hw
```

And to connect the modem I do:

```
pi@raspi-sort:~ $ sudo nmcli con up "LTE Connection" 
Connection successfully activated (D-Bus active path: /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/ActiveConnection/3)
```

And check if it's up... this is the first thing that looks odd to me:

```
cdc-wdm0: connected to LTE Connection
    modem (qmi_wwan), hw, iface wwan
    inet4 10.0.0.4/24
```

Then try using ping to check the connection, but it just doesn't work:

```
pi@raspi-sort:~ $ ping -I wwan0 8.8.8.8
PING 8.8.8.8 (8.8.8.8) from 10.0.0.4 wwan0: 56(84) bytes of data.
```

LTE Connection is defined as:

```
pi@raspi-sort:~ $ nmcli con show "LTE Connection"
connection.id:                          LTE Connection
connection.uuid:                        0993532f-4bd9-4703-a6b6-be3a1c20533d
connection.stable-id:                   --
connection.interface-name:              cdc-wdm0
connection.type:                        gsm
connection.autoconnect:                 no
connection.autoconnect-priority:        0
connection.autoconnect-retries:         -1 (default)
connection.timestamp:                   1546902293
connection.read-only:                   no
connection.permissions:                 
connection.zone:                        --
connection.master:                      --
connection.slave-type:                  --
connection.autoconnect-slaves:          -1 (default)
connection.secondaries:                 
connection.gateway-ping-timeout:        0
connection.metered:                     unknown
connection.lldp:                        -1 (default)
ipv4.method:                            auto
ipv4.dns:                               
ipv4.dns-search:                        
ipv4.dns-options:                       (default)
ipv4.dns-priority:                      0
ipv4.addresses:                         
ipv4.gateway:                           --
ipv4.routes:                            
ipv4.route-metric:                      -1
ipv4.ignore-auto-routes:                no
ipv4.ignore-auto-dns:                   no
ipv4.dhcp-client-id:                    --
ipv4.dhcp-timeout:                      0
ipv4.dhcp-send-hostname:                yes
ipv4.dhcp-hostname:                     --
ipv4.dhcp-fqdn:                         --
ipv4.never-default:                     no
ipv4.may-fail:                          yes
ipv4.dad-timeout:                       -1 (default)
ipv6.method:                            auto
ipv6.dns:                               
ipv6.dns-search:                        
ipv6.dns-options:                       (default)
ipv6.dns-priority:                      0
ipv6.addresses:                         
ipv6.gateway:                           --
ipv6.routes:                            
ipv6.route-metric:                      -1
ipv6.ignore-auto-routes:                no
ipv6.ignore-auto-dns:                   no
ipv6.never-default:                     no
ipv6.may-fail:                          yes
ipv6.ip6-privacy:                       -1 (unknown)
ipv6.addr-gen-mode:                     stable-privacy
ipv6.dhcp-send-hostname:                yes
ipv6.dhcp-hostname:                     --
ipv6.token:                             --
gsm.number:                             --
gsm.username:                           wap
gsm.password:                           <hidden>
gsm.password-flags:                     0 (none)
gsm.apn:                                wap.gprs.unifon.com.ar
gsm.network-id:                         --
gsm.pin:                                <hidden>
gsm.pin-flags:                          0 (none)
gsm.home-only:                          no
gsm.device-id:                          --
gsm.sim-id:                             --
gsm.sim-operator-id:                    --
proxy.method:                           auto
proxy.browser-only:                     no
proxy.pac-url:                          --
proxy.pac-script:                       --
GENERAL.NAME:                           LTE Connection
GENERAL.UUID:                           0993532f-4bd9-4703-a6b6-be3a1c20533d
GENERAL.DEVICES:                        cdc-wdm0
GENERAL.STATE:                          activated
GENERAL.DEFAULT:                        no
GENERAL.DEFAULT6:                       no
GENERAL.VPN:                            no
GENERAL.ZONE:                           --
GENERAL.DBUS-PATH:                      /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/ActiveConnection/3
GENERAL.CON-PATH:                       /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Settings/1
GENERAL.SPEC-OBJECT:                    --
GENERAL.MASTER-PATH:                    --
IP4.ADDRESS[1]:                         10.0.0.4/24
IP4.GATEWAY:                            10.0.0.5
IP4.DNS[1]:                             10.0.0.1
```

My experience is a bit limited to be able to debug this issue further - I've been stuck here for a while... so any directions to understand what's going on will be appreciated.

Comment: `Network manager` isn't supported by Raspbian Stretch by default. Did you install it? What did you do with `dhcpcd`?

Comment: Yes I installed it, and did `sudo systemctl disable dhcpcd` and `sudo systemctl stop dhcpcd`.  I believe that's all I did to make my wifi network interface work for me.  I installed it in order to have ModemManager too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What helped me debug this issue was using this route testing command, to realize the default gateway was off.  My IP for the modem interface was `10.0.0.4` and the default gateway should've been `10.0.0.5`.

Running this command:

`ip route get to 8.8.8.8 from 10.0.0.4`

Was returning `192.168.1.1` as the gateway.

So in conclusion, the solution was 2-folded:

1. On one hand I had two default routes when running `ip route`.  I removed the one I didn't want to have.
2. On the other hand the Netgear 779s was just not letting pings go through.  The problem was that I was relying on it to know when the connection was up, which is evidently not a great idea.  Still not sure why, since there doesn't seem to be any configuration for ICMP within the modem setup, but that's a different story.